# Can you use Redirect and Proxypass at the same time

Tags: apache-2.2, tomcat, redirect, proxypass

I am using Apache 2.2.15 on CentOS to provide SSL for a TomCat application.

```
ProxyPass / http://127.0.0.1:8090/ connectiontimeout=300 timeout=300
ProxyPassReverse / http://127.0.0.1:8090
```

This works fine and everything is great; however, I want to add the following line:

```
Redirect permanent /broken/page.html https://www.servername.com/correct/page.html
```

before the above to handle an error in the TomCat application itself. However, it does not appear to work the way I expect (i.e, it appears to do nothing and change nothing). Is it possible to use Redirect this way? I don't have the ability to edit the application, unfortunately.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Yes!  Above the `ProxyPass /`, add:

```
ProxyPass /broken/page.html !
```

That'll force the proxypass to not act on the page that you're trying to redirect.

Comment: Thank you! I was wondering if I had to do something like that, but I thought that having it come first might be enough. Works great!

Comment: Another example over on stackoverflow: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26595592/use-redirect-and-proxypass/34501420#34501420

Comment: What if you need to exclude based on query string?

Answer (score 13):

[`<Proxy>` blocks](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_proxy.html#proxy) are also useful as the context is always understood to be applying to proxied traffic. In this fashion you don't need to exclude specific paths.

```
<Proxy *>
    Redirect permanent /broken/page.html https://www.example.com/correct/page.html
    RedirectMatch ^/deadstuff.+ http://www.example.com/correct/page.html
</Proxy>

ProxyPass / http://127.0.0.1:8090/ connectiontimeout=300 timeout=300
ProxyPassReverse / http://127.0.0.1:8090
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer, far easier to setup for complex setups.